# Will combining 3 javascript blocks relating to Google Universal Analytics improve/decrease page load time by any significant amount?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

It's my understanding that optimized webpages should contain as few javascript blocks as possible to improve/decrease page load time.

Would combining the following 3 blocks, each of which measures a different event through Google Analytics, A) be possible, and B) create any meaningful impact in decreasing/improving page load times?

```
<script>
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>


<script language="javascript">

EventNONInteraction = true;
Frequency = 4; 
GA_EventCategory = 'category2'; 
GA_EventAction = 'down'; //

_frequency = Frequency;
_repentance = 100 / Frequency;
var _scrollMatrix = new Array();
for (ix = 0; ix < _repentance; ix++) {
    _scrollMatrix[ix] = [_frequency, 'false'];
    _frequency = Frequency + _frequency;
}
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    for (iz = 0; iz < _scrollMatrix.length; iz++) {
        if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() * _scrollMatrix[iz][0] / 100)  && (_scrollMatrix[iz][1]== 'false')) {
            _scrollMatrix[iz][1] = 'true';
            ga('send', 'event', GA_EventCategory, GA_EventAction, _scrollMatrix[iz][0]+'%', {'nonInteraction': EventNONInteraction});  
        }
    }
});
</script>


<script language="javascript">

if (document.referrer.match(/google\./gi) && document.referrer.match(/cd/gi)) {
  var myString = document.referrer;
  var r        = myString.match(/cd=(.*?)&/);
  var rank     = parseInt(r[1]);
  var kw       = myString.match(/q=(.*?)&/);

  if (kw[1].length > 0) {
    var keyWord  = decodeURI(kw[1]);
  } else {
    keyWord = "(not provided)";
  }

  var p        = document.location.pathname;
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'RankTracker', keyWord, p, rank, true]);
}
</script>
```

If yes to both, how do I correctly combine the blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining those three inline script tags is certainly possible.  Just paste the code all into one script tag instead of three separate ones.

And, combining separate scripts that are each externally loading JS files (which isn't what you have) can make a meaningful difference in page load time because there are fewer resources to download over the internet or find and load from the cache.  This is probably where your understanding comes from.

But, combining your multiple inline script tags into just one script tag likely won't even be noticeable because it doesn't affect any sort of external load time other than just a couple bytes of download you might save (which by itself likely isn't noticeable).

Comment: Thank you; to confirm for future reference - I can essentially lump the script tags together by removing all but the first <script> and last </script>?  Lastly, how do I make sure these newly combined, and any potential future, inline script tags do not interfere with each?

Comment: @user3299651 - Yes to your confirmation on combining.  Separate script tags don't offer protection from interference.  All variables or functions declared at the top scope in a script tag are available to any other scripts too.  About the only thing I can think of that is different with separate scripts is that if one script throws an exception upon initialization, it won't stop the other script tags from executing, but if they were all in one script tag it would stop them.  But, assuming you don't throw any uncaught exceptions in your initialization, this shouldn't be a problem.